# Swift - UIButton image on bigger screen programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uibutton

I'm trying to programmatically style my button using swift

```
let acButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as! UIButton
acButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)
acButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "ac"), forState: .Normal)
acButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10,10,10,10)
acButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
acButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
acButton.addTarget(self, action: "acPressed", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(acButton)
```

but i've got little problems on bigger screen devices like iPad Air (see image) the image doesn't fit the button frame, i also tried setting the image as backgroundImage of the button but i didn't get what i want cause **imageEdgeInsets** doesn't seems to be working on backgroundImage.

[image]

**Solution:**

get the image using `imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation`, as in the following method:

```
func getScaledImage(img: UIImage, btn: UIButton) -> UIImage {

        // Check which dimension (width or height) to pay respect to and
        // calculate the scale factor
        var imgRatio: CGFloat = img.size.width / img.size.height
        var btnRatio = btn.frame.size.width / btn.frame.size.height
        var scaleFactor = (imgRatio > btnRatio) ? img.size.width / btn.frame.size.width : img.size.height / btn.frame.size.height

        // Create image using scale factor
        var scaledImg = UIImage(CGImage: img.CGImage, scale: scaleFactor, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Up)
        return scaledImg!

    }
```

To implement this we would write:

```
let acImage = getScaledImage(UIImage(named: "ac")!, btn: acButton)
acButton.setImage(acImage, forState: .Normal)
```

so here the **final code**:

```
let acButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as! UIButton
acButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)

let acImage = getScaledImage(UIImage(named: "ac")!, btn: acButton)
acButton.setImage(acImage, forState: .Normal)

acButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20)
acButton.addTarget(self, action: "acPressed", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
basicCalculatorView.addSubview(acButton)
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to add constraints? That should scale it just fine.

Comment: what constraints should i add? note that i need to set button width and height programmatically

Answer (score 0):

you might need to set the **contentMode** of your `UIButton`:

```
    acButton.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set backgroundImage rather than setting just image.

```
acButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "image.jpg"), forState: .Normal)
```

Check if it works

Comment: i said: "i also tried setting the image as backgroundImage of the button but i didn't get what i want cause imageEdgeInsets doesn't seems to be working on backgroundImage"

Comment: Weird problem. Also try this: set cliptobound to true for button